# Save sources to images rendered on server using Js

Tags: javascript, python

I pass array with pictures generated on server. Later I iterate like this:

```
    {% for picture in picturess %}
<div id="someid" class="col-md-12">
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ picture}}" width="800" height="600" alt="graph">
</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

How Can I pass it to javascript array? If I call the get element by id I got only the last pictures source

Comment: Add a `class` attribute to the `img` element and then do `document.getElementsByClassName` - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: Yeah I figured it out already too. I have placed the id in the wrong place - my bad. Thank you. Can you move your answer so I could mark that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `class` attribute to the `img` element and then do `document.getElementsByClassName`.